# How to find the tables and their associated columns referenced in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to list out all the tables and their associated columns which are referenced in a stored procedure.

How can i do it in oracle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't think you can get the column level dependencies using any oracle view. You can get table level direct dependencies using *_dependencies view. If you need to get the column level information you will have to parse the *_source view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get tables referenced using this query

```
SELECT referenced_owner, 
       referenced_name, 
       referenced_type 
FROM   dba_dependencies 
WHERE  name = 'MYPROC' 
       AND owner = 'SCOTT' 
ORDER  BY referenced_owner, 
          referenced_name, 
          referenced_type;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get all table dependencies in all_dependecies view.
If dynamic sql is using in one procedure then the table won't be in dba_dependecies view.
So in that case, you could see the table in dba_source (if table name in not a parameter of the function!)